# Evaluate the integral $\int \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{9-x^2}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

How to evaluate the integral $x^2/\sqrt{9-x^2}$

So I use trigonometric substitution where $x = 3\sin(\theta)$

And I got down to:

$$
\frac 9 2 (\theta - \sin(2\theta)/2) + C
$$

What do I do from here?

Comment: Substitute $\theta=\sin^{-1}(x)$ and make use of $\sin(2\theta)=2\sin\theta\cos\theta$

Comment: Make a triangle to relate theta with x and sine.

Comment: @DavidPeterson thanks very much homie, works like a charm i got it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
x & = 3\sin\theta \\[8pt]
\frac x 3 & = \sin\theta \\[8pt]
\arcsin \frac x 3 & = \theta \\[8pt]
\sin(2\theta) & = 2\sin\theta\cos\theta \\[8pt]
& = 2\cdot \frac x 3 \cdot \cos\left(\arcsin\frac x 3 \right) \\[8pt]
& = \frac{2x} 3 \cdot \frac{\sqrt{3^2-x^2}} 3.
\end{align}

Comment: thx homie, i got exactly what u got

Answer (score 1):

Hint : $ \sin( 2\theta) = 2 \sin( \theta) \cos( \theta)$ and 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\cos( \sin^{-1}( X)) = \sqrt{ 1-(\sin( \sin^{-1}(X))^2} =\sqrt{1-X^2} .
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively write the numerator as $$9-(9-x^2)$$

Use 
http://www.sosmath.com/tables/integral/integ13/integ13.html